# Bowler improving his pace significantly after coming to international cricket?

Tags: cricket

Is their a bowler in the cricket history who has increased his pace significantly so that before he was a medium pacer and then called a fast bowler in  international circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, many bowlers at starting carrier bowl with very low pace in cricket club matches. After putting too much efforts and daily practices made them speedy/pacer bowler. One example is like ***Wahab Riaz***  Pakistani player (left hand fast bowler)in the beginning bowl with average of 120 to 130 Kph. After polishing them self ,bowl with 140 to 150 kph in international matches.

***Reference:***
http://www.espncricinfo.com/icc-cricket-world-cup-2015/content/story/854113.html